# Graph query to get outgoing messages to external recipients

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to find a single graph query to get messages (emails) sent by me to external recipient/s (not from my organization).
The response should include an email that was sent to both internal and external recipients.
Is it possible?
I tried filtering by toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients but these are not filterable.
Also tried the $search query parameter but couldn't find a way to find emails that contains at least one recipients whose domain is not @mydomain.com.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot filter it on a single call since there is no such property that decides whether the recipient is external or internal. Please raise a feature request for this in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot filter it on a single call since there is no such property that decides whether the recipient is external or internal. You need to filter them on your end(By code) whether it belongs to your organization or not. You can raise a feature request for this in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that it may be implemented in the future.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's a MAPI attribute on the email itself that shows if the email has external recipients?